# Flutter navigate to page with default Material Drawer

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, dart

What is the best why to navigate to a page in flutter using the default Material Drawer.
I'm still learning how to work with Flutter.

In Android we used to anvigate to a fragment page, but how does this work in Flutter ?

I just want to understand how to navigate to an drawer item without without using bloc's.

[image: Screenshot of app]

```
class MdDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MdDrawer({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('MyPage'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(

        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[

            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: const Text(_AccountName),
              accountEmail: const Text(_AccountEmail),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
                child: Text(_AccountAbbr),
              ),
            ),

            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
              title: Text('Notes'),
              onTap: () => _alertOnListTileTap(context),
            ),

            Divider(),

            ...

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _alertOnListTileTap(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      child: AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Not Implemented'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: const Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ExampleWidget()));` ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'll take a closer look

Answer (score 0):

Doing this without using bloc will make your code difficult to manage as it scales unless you just need an app prototype without any business logic.

Nonetheless, you can do it without bloc as follows;

1. Place all you screen in the `body:` as a list which displays the appropriate screen by indexing. like

> ```
> body: [
>       Expenses(),
>       Inspiration()
>       Personal(),
>       Work(),
>       More(),
>     ].elementAt(selectedIndex),
> ```

```
drawer: MdDrawer(onTap: (int val){
                setState(() {
                    this._selectedIndex=val;
                 });
              } 
,)
```

Now you can push the desired body to display by providing the index as the return value of the `Navigator.of(context).pop(index)` or a callback function into `MdDrawer`. We will to do the callback function method. The index return will be used to update the state using setState.

```
class MdDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title; final Function onTap;

  MdDrawer({Key key, this.title, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('MyPage'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(


        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[

            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: const Text(_AccountName),
              accountEmail: const Text(_AccountEmail),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
                child: Text(_AccountAbbr),
              ),
            ),

            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
              title: Text('Notes'),
              onTap: () => _alertOnListTileTap(context, 0),
            ),
           ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
              title: Text('Expenses'),
              onTap: () => _alertOnListTileTap(context, 1),
            ),

            Divider(),

            ...

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _alertOnListTileTap(BuildContext context, int index ) {
    onTap(indext);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();

  }
}
```

I hope this helps